# How to discard unpublished changes in django-cms?

Tags: django-cms

I already found out there's **no way** to discard unpublished changes in django-cms **from the Admin**. Therefore I'm looking for a way to hotfix this **from the shell via ORM**.

I see there's a **Page** model which has 2 instances for each page, one **public** and one **draft**. Is it perhaps possible to discard those changes by copying some particular data from the public instance to the draft instance? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `Page` menu you select "Revert to live" and that'll discard the draft changes.

[image: Page menu]

Comment: I see this has been [added in 3.4.2](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.4.x/upgrade/3.4.2.html) but we're running 3.4.0 still. I'd try to go and mimick the behavior in shell but since the release notes mention a "complete rewrite of revision handling system" I think the only reasonable way is just upgrade and use the new feature.

Comment: @JozefKnaperek in older versions you could find 'revert to live' in the history menu. I think this menu was merged with the 'Page' menu in the newer versions. I've based this on a site we have running something like CMS 3.1

Comment: I can't find any "history menu", are you sure it's not provided by some optional plugin?

Comment: Hello @JozefKnaperek, I highly recommend upgrading to the latest 3.4.x version. The patch releases are fully backwards compatible and easy to upgrade.